# Restricting a file on a network

Tags: java, networking

I'm currently running a Java app over a network and I'm using one system as the server. The clients can create documents such as receipts and other things but they're all stored on a folder in the server system. But now I have an issue the folder had to be shared and it's permission set to read and write for every client to be able to read and write to that folder and cos of this users can directly access this folder on the network and see the files or even delete the files in the folder but I don't want this.

So is it possible to have a folder where all clients can read or write files to on the server system but cannot directly access the folder through the network?

Comment: The way this is normally done (and I strongly recommend you do the same) is that clients have **no** access to the file system of the server at all. They just send the data to the server application, which is then responsible for reading/writing its own files, **after making sure that the data they got from the client is valid**.

Comment: I don't understand. How do I do this with a java desktop app?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would have a service, such as a web service which allows users to upload files. There is command line tools to do this as well as being able to do this with a web browser.  There is a number of way of doing this based on your preferred choice.

Another approach is to give each use a folder they and only they can access (your application also). One folder per client/user. You can monitor these folders and detect when a new file appears and move it to a folder only your can access.

Comment: This seems like an idea that would only work within a web app. But I'm talking about a desktop app developed using J2SE

Comment: @Charles the second approach works without a web server. You can use a web app or server with JSE. A simple one is https://eclipse.org/jetty/